# Add border to value of radio button upon checked (jquery/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I want to add a border (not outline) to the "YES" value when the yes radio button is checked. I am able to put an `onchange` event on the input radio button, but I am unable to add a border to the "YES" value since there is no label tag. How do I do that with jquery/javascript?

I've tried

```
$("input:radio[name='registered'][value='yes']").css("border","3px solid red");
```

but that doesn't even give the checkbox a border (only works if I change to outline), let alone the value of the checkbox. Any thoughts? Ideally, the HTML file would be untouched and all changes made in the js file. The examples I see mostly have label tags or divs added, but this is without any tags for me to use. i tried .value.css() but its not valid.

```
<form name="input" method="get">
        <span>Registered:</span>
        <input type="radio" name="registered" value="yes">YES  
        <input type="radio" name="registered" value="no" checked disabled>NO
</form>
```

Comment: Wrapping the text in an element like a `<span>` would be the least painful solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use any element in **YES** or **NO** text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(e) {
       $(this).next("span").css("border","2px solid red");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="input" method="get">
   <span>Registered:</span>
   <input type="radio" name="registered" value="yes">
   <span>YES</span> 
   <input type="radio" name="registered" value="no" checked disabled>
   <span>NO</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No javascript needed. You can use `:checked` selector. Also you should wrap your text with span.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked:not(:disabled) + span{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form name="input" method="get">
  <span>Registered:</span>
  <input type="radio" name="registered" value="yes"><span>YES</span>
  <input type="radio" name="registered" value="no" checked disabled><span>NO</span>
</form>
```